# Having trouble with setting up C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting a common error on the issue that I'm having but nothing has worked:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
```

I've been told to download the C++ dev kit again, the Windows SDK again, Reset my PC after download and manually change the path inside the file that can't find it.

As it turns out the file exists (and the Windows SDK too, I assume), Visual studio is just looking for it in the wrong spot, So I figure this is a setup issue. It exists in this location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt`. You could say why not just manually link to it? I have but then another file can't be found, so I change that and then another one can't be found and so on. I'd appreciate the help as this is the reason I get scared to use Visual Studio and go back running to Code, thank you!

Comment: Do you use IDE or command line (to compile)?

Comment: @tansy I use Visual Studio to compile

Comment: So, You mean IDE. There are options to set directories for libraries, includes and stuff. Check whether directory containing `crtdbg.h` is set there up.

Comment: Make sure that VS properties, for the project, is using the correct Windows SDK.

Comment: @ChrisMM @tansy Ok I included it as a library in properties, now it gives me this error: `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib` I haven't seen it before

Answer (score -1):

Does this issue also occur if I create an empty C++ project and build it? If it works fine, this issue is more relevant to your current project.

Please check the target platform version of your project. Right click the project name and select ‘Properties’—‘Configuration Properties’—‘General’— ‘Windows SDK Version’ like the following, and select the Windows 10 SDK to have a try.[image]

You could also refer to the method in this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a2f61b7-3c01-4767-9a30-e897dc240e60/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-ucrtdlib?forum=vssetup).

(PS:You need to make sure that the SDK you install is consistent with the operating system, for example if you use Win 11 then you should install the Windows 11 SDK.)